# Prove that for any integers $x, y$ and $z$ and any integer $k$that if $x \equiv_k y$ and $y \equiv_k z$ then $x \equiv_k z$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I was wondering if my proof is right and if there are better methods of solving this proof?

My proof:

Assume  $x \equiv_k y$ and  $y \equiv_k z$ is true. This means that :

\begin{align}x &= y + kq,&&\text{where }\;q ∈\Bbb Z,\tag{1} \\
y &= z + ka,&& \text{where } a ∈ \Bbb Z. \tag{2}
\end{align}

By substitution of $(2)$ into $(1)$ we get:

\begin{align} x &= z + ka + kq \\
  &= z + k(a + q),&&\qquad \text{where }\: a ∈\Bbb Z \text{ and } q ∈ \Bbb Z
\end{align}

This proves $x \equiv_k z$ is true. $\blacksquare$

Comment: It's fine for me (except the formulæ code…).

Comment: you have shown congruence to be a transitive relation

Comment: Your argument is fine, but you might have mentioned that $(a+q)$ is an integer just before the "This proves..." punch line.  Also, the symbol $\equiv_k$ is not standard, even though your use of it here makes it perfectly clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Direct alternate proof.
k|x - y, k|y - z, k|x - y + y - z = x - z.